# ¿Cómo enviar la posición al Observar un array en un Viewmodel?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, observable, viewmodel

tengo implementada toda la estructura de una arquitectura MVVM con jetpack pero no se como observar cada posición de un array, para observar una propiedad solo se hace asi:

```
var normales=""
    @Bindable get
    set(v){
        field=v
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.normales)
    }
```

con un array de tipo map<String, String> necesitaría el índice porque no seria cómodo recorrer todo el array para saber cual cambio, para observar el cambio lo tengo asi:

```
inner class ArrayWrapper(vararg pairs: Pair<String, String>) :LinkedHashMap<String, String>(pairs.size) {
    override fun put(key: String, value: String): String {
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.calibre)
        return super.put(key,value)!!
    }
}

var calibre= ArrayWrapper("C2" to "", "C3" to "", "C4" to "", "C5" to "", "C6+" to "")
    @Bindable get
```

esto sirve muy bien pero actualmente tengo el observador asi:

```
viewModel.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(object: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback(){
        override fun onPropertyChanged(sender: Observable?, propertyId: Int) {
            when(propertyId){
                BR.calibre-> Log.i("cambio calibres","asi "+ viewModel.calibre.toString())
                else-> Log.i("hola","notificaron")
            }
        }
    })
```

y la salida me da:

```
I/cambio calibres: asi {C2=56, C3=4, C4=, C5=, C6+=}
I/cambio calibres: asi {C2=56, C3=4, C4=, C5=5, C6+=}
```

entonces como puedo saber cual índice cambio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de responder, voy a mostrarte cómo mejorar la forma de crear observables porque estás escribiendo mucho código innecesario. Tu sentido de programador debería ser capaz de detectar que tu solución es demasiado compleja para un problema tan simple.

Cosas incesarias que estás haciendo:

- crear un `ArrayWrapper`
- notificar cada vez cambia el valor de una propiedad
- agregar la anotación `@Bindable`
- implementar la interfaz `Observable`

Entonces cuál es la forma correcta de implementarlo? La respuesta está en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture)

> There are multiple ways to implement observability. You can use observable classes, observable fields, or, the preferred way, LiveData.

Todo lo que debes hacer es envolver en un `LiveData` cualquier objeto que quieras observar

```
val calibre = MutableLiveData(
    mapOf(
        "C2" to "",
        "C3" to "",
        "C4" to "",
        "C5" to "",
        "C6+" to ""
    )
)
```

Ahora la solución para saber que índice cambió es agregar otra propiedad observable

```
class ExampleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    val calibre = MutableLiveData(
        mapOf(
            "C2" to "",
            "C3" to "",
            "C4" to "",
            "C5" to "",
            "C6+" to ""
        )
    )
    val keyChanged = MutableLiveData<String>()
    
    fun updateCalibre(key: String, value: String) {
        calibre.value?.let { currentMap ->
            calibre.value = currentMap + Pair(key, value) //concat array
            keyChanged.value = key
        }
    }
    
}
```

Luego en tu activity lo observas así

```
viewModel.calibre.observe(this) { calibres ->
    Log.i("cambio calibres", "asi $calibres")
}
viewModel.keyChanged.observe(this) { indice ->
    Log.i("cambio calibres", "cambió índice $indice")
}
```

Comment: si quiero hacer un doble enlace de datos con ese array cambia mucho? es que esta función `updateCalibre` no me serviría en ese caso porque seria `android:text="@={modelo.calibre['C3']}"`

Comment: Sí, probablemente tengas que agregar más líneas de las que termines ahorrando. Puede que una mejor solución sea usar un [ObservableArrayMap](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#observable_Collections). Procura agregar en tus preguntas cuál es problema que intentas resolver. De lo contrario recibirás soluciones generales que tal vez no sean las más adecuadas para tu caso particular. En esta pregunta debiste mencionar por qué necesitabas saber que índice cambio.